# Parse json data list retrieved from post api call in Android

Tags: java, android, json

my json data is

{
"code": 0,
"msg": 0,
"data": [
  {
"id": 12,
"name": "白织灯",
"url": "http://1u1m.dev/s/12",
"code": 12,
"type": "3"
},
  {
"id": 16,
"name": "白织灯",
"url": "http://1u1m.dev/s/16",
"code": 16,
"type": "3"
}

my java model is

```
public class BatchList {

    private List<BatchLala> data;


    public List<BatchLala> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<BatchLala> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }


    public static class BatchLala {
        private int id;
        private int name;
        private int url;
        private int code;
        private int type;



        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public int getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public int getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public int getCode() {
            return code;
        }

        public int getType() {
            return type;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public void setName(int name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public void setUrl(int url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public void setCode(int code) {
            this.code = code;
        }

        public void setType(int type) {
            this.type = type;
        }

    }
}
```

how to for this all data

now i use  but now is error

```
    public void onSuccess(BatchList result) {
        if (result != null) {

            for (BatchList.BatchLala result:getData()) {

            }
```

i want ask how to foreach this data
thanks

Comment: `how to for this all data` how to what? `private int name;
        private int url;` in your JSON this fields are not int.

Comment: What are you using to parse the data?

Answer (score 0):

you should use Gson Library, its best library to conver model to json and json to models. you can use this tutorial to learn how to use Gson

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaLibrary-Gson/article.html